# Generate toString method with ant

Tags: ant, jaxb, jax-ws, xjc, wsimport

I have .wsdl files and using wsimport I'm generating classes to use the webservices.

The problem is that I need to add toString method to the generated classes. I saw that it is possible in the xjc but can't find a way to do it in wsimport.

Do you know how to approach this?

At the moment the function looks like that

```
    <basename property="basename.file" file="${file}" />
    <mkdir dir="/tmp" />
    <exec executable="wsimport">
        <arg value="-catalog" />
        <arg value="jax-ws-catalog.xml" />
        <arg value="-s" />
        <arg value="${src.generated}" />
        <arg value="-keep" />
        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="/temp" />
        <arg value="-Xnocompile" />
        <arg value="file://mock_${basename.file}" />
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [link](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-ts.html)

The CXF XJC toString Plugin provides and XJC plugin that updates the generated beans to implement toString methods to override the default Object.toString method. It uses Apache Commons Lang ToStringBuilder class to build the String, so commons-lang.jar needs to be available on the classpath.

Add the argument -Xts

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) a power package of XJC plugins.

You can use the [ToString](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/ToString+plugin) from [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) for this. It uses a "strategic" approach similar to `commons-lang` but generates reflection-free code - meaning the generated `toString()` methods will be pretty fast.

You'll get generated something like:

```
public String toString() {
    final ToStringStrategy strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    append(null, buffer, strategy);
    return buffer.toString();
}

public StringBuilder append(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
    strategy.appendStart(locator, this, buffer);
    appendFields(locator, buffer, strategy);
    strategy.appendEnd(locator, this, buffer);
    return buffer;
}

public StringBuilder appendFields(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
    {
        USAddress theShipTo;
        theShipTo = this.getShipTo();
        strategy.appendField(locator, this, "shipTo", buffer, theShipTo);
    }
    {
        USAddress theBillTo;
        theBillTo = this.getBillTo();
        strategy.appendField(locator, this, "billTo", buffer, theBillTo);
    }
    // ...
    return buffer;
}
```

Ant usage is more or les as follows:

```
<target name="generate-sources">
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task">
        <!-- XJC2 Task classpath -->
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
                <include name="activation-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb-api-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb-impl-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb-runtime-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb-core-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jsr173_api-*.jar"/>
                <include name="stax-api-*.jar"/>

                <include name="jaxb-xjc-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb2-basics-ant-*.jar"/>

                <include name="slf4j-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jcl-over-slf4j-*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc"/>
    <xjc destdir="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc" extension="true">
        <arg line="
            -Xequals
            -XhashCode
            -Xinheritance
            -XtoString
            -Xcopyable
            -XenumValue"/>
        <binding dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources">
            <include name="**/*.xjb"/>
        </binding>
        <schema dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources">
            <include name="**/*.xsd"/>
        </schema>
        <!-- Plugins -->
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
                <include name="jaxb2-basics-plugins-*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </xjc>
</target>
```

The [distribution](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/releases) has a ready-to-run Ant sample (see `jaxb2-basics-sample-basic-<VERSION>-ant-src.zip`).